# output element in array upon scanf - C

Tags: c

I'm trying out a simple input/output in array.
basically, when user input 1,
it will loop through the array and print the first element a[0]
after which, when I input 1 again, it will print the second element a[1], and so forth.

However, right now, when I input 1,
only the first element a[0] will be printed out.
May I know why is this so?
I would like to print out the subsequent array element when I input 1.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int i;
    int ch;
     char *A[] = {"Hello", "Good", "Bye", "Name"};

    while (ch == 1){
            printf("enter number");
            scanf("%s",&ch);
       for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        printf("Value = %s\n", A[i]);
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

**current output**

```
Enter number: 1
Hello
Enter number: 1
Hello
```

**desired output**

```
Enter number: 1
Hello
Enter number: 1
Good
Enter number: 1
Bye
```

Comment: `=` assigns, `==` compares.

Comment: Mistake one `ch = 1` - This is assignment - not comparison

Comment: Mistake two - Only four items in the array

Comment: Mistake three `for (i = 0; i <= 5; ++i){` should be `for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i){`

Comment: Mistake four - Perhaps a `fllush(stdout)` after the `printf` so the user will see the prompt

Comment: @Stack - Let the compiler do it - put `[]` instead of `[4]`

Comment: ... And sort out the formatting - get the braces to be in the same column

Comment: Mistack five - Initialise ch before the while loop

Comment: @EdHeal I'm new to C

Comment: That is obvious . Hope you are learing

Comment: Please compile will all the warnings enabled

Comment: @Stack - Please do not edit the question - But add to it as a commentary. People will come back to this and want to understand the process

Comment: @EdHeal are you able to guide me regarding the output that I desired?

Comment: Perhaps learning to use a debugger would be a good course of action

Comment: sigh, still unable to get it.

Comment: What happens when the user does not enter `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass `int*` to `scanf` for reading data via `%s`.

Your loop is completely wrong. Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int ch = 1;
    const char *A[] = {"Hello", "Good", "Bye", "Name"};

    while (ch == 1){
        printf("enter number");
        if (scanf("%d",&ch) != 1) ch = 0;
        printf("Value = %s\n", A[i]);
        i++;
        if (i >= (int)(sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]))) ch = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or to match the "desired output":

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h> /* to use strcmp */
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int ch = 1;
    const char *A[] = {"Hello", "Good", "Bye", "Name"};

    while (ch == 1){
        printf("Enter number: ");
        if (scanf("%d",&ch) != 1) ch = 0;
        printf("%s\n", A[i]);
        if (strcmp(A[i], "Bye") == 0) break;
        i++;
        if (i >= (int)(sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]))) ch = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I know what's the different with those 2?